# Why would capybara feature specs fail when run together, only for me. but pass when separately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, ui-testing, gui-testing

This would seem to be due to a local configuration problem but nothing I've tried has helped and I am stuck.

When I run our rspec-capybara feature spec called "user_save_quote" I got 5/8 failures.  However when I run each of the (failing) line numbers individually they pass.  Moreover when other developers run this spec in its entirety each test passes for them.

I've tried the following but none of them helped:

- switching to the firefox  driver
- removing my `.bashrc` file
- removing lastpass from Chrome
- running specs from a non-tmux session
- run with and without `bundle exec` prefix
- `rake db:migrate`, `rake db:seed` and `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:test:prepare`
- closing all apps and restarting my computer

The visual behavior in the application is to create a user and then login but a subsequent attempt to do those things just seems to hang for 10 seconds then fail.
I've tried switching to the firefox driver but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your spec helper.

It may be caused because user already created,and for next spec you are try to create it again

```
config.before do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

and check your factory if you are use it,add `sequence`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.sequence(:name) { |n| "sir-#{n}-#{rand(99999)}" }
    f.sequence(:email) { |n| "sir#{n}#{rand(99999)}@example.com" }
end
```